# Где лучше применять Critical Sections, Semaphore, Mutex, Events?

Tags: c++, winapi

Всегда можно по разному извратиться, но хотелось бы лучшего понимания о том, что целесообразней применить в той или иной ситуации.

У меня есть свое небольшое виденье. К примеру, если нужно защитить от одновременного доступа к каким-либо данным, то подойдут мьютексы и критические секции, но критические секции будут быстрее, так что нужно выбирать их, если  только не нужен доступ к этому объекту со второго процесса.
Семафоры лучше использовать когда есть поток производитель и поток потребитель, к примеру, нужно отсортировать массив по возрастанию в отдельном потоке и выводить каждый готовый элемент в главном потоке.
События нужны для ситуаций, когда нужно вывести из ожидания много потоков(слабо понимаю реальное применение и почему тоже самое не проще сделать с семафорами или мьютексами).
В общем, как видите, по знаниям в этом вопросе у меня только базовый фарш состоящий из неполной теории и оторванный от реальной практики.